# Ansible Change MAC Address Format (Remove Periods)

Tags: regex, ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a file that has the following lines.

IPX,10.153.34.97,255.255.255.0,0002.c18b.f128,,,
IPX,10.153.34.101,255.255.255.0,0002.c18b.ed10,,,
IPX,10.153.34.104,255.255.255.0,0002.c18c.1a43,,,
IPX,10.153.34.111,255.255.255.0,0002.c18b.f93e,,,
IPX,10.153.34.113,255.255.255.0,0002.c18c.3148,,,
IPX,10.153.34.115,255.255.255.0,0002.c18c.30e8,,,

I am trying to use Ansible to edit the MAC address to look like the following (remove the periods from the MAC):

IPX,10.153.34.97,255.255.255.0,0002c18bf128,,,
IPX,10.153.34.101,255.255.255.0,0002c18bed10,,,
IPX,10.153.34.104,255.255.255.0,0002c18c1a43,,,
IPX,10.153.34.111,255.255.255.0,0002c18bf93e,,,
IPX,10.153.34.113,255.255.255.0,0002c18c3148,,,
IPX,10.153.34.115,255.255.255.0,0002c18c30e8,,,

My Ansible version is 2.12.10 and my code is the following:

```
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  tasks:
  - name: Replace periods in MAC.
    replace:
      path: /home/test/ansible-mac-export/test-export3
      regexp: ([0-9a-f]{4}[\.][0-9a-f]{4}[\.][0-9a-f]{4})
      replace: ([0-9a-f]{4}[0-9a-f]{4}[0-9a-f]{4})
```

Obviously the fault is with my replace statement. However, I can't figure out how to change it to be what I need. I have also tried the following replace line without any success.

```
replace: '\1'
```

I know that I'm really close, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the file for testing

```
shell> cat /tmp/test.csv
IPX,10.153.34.97,255.255.255.0,0002.c18b.f128,,,
IPX,10.153.34.101,255.255.255.0,0002.c18b.ed10,,,
IPX,10.153.34.104,255.255.255.0,0002.c18c.1a43,,,
IPX,10.153.34.111,255.255.255.0,0002.c18b.f93e,,,
IPX,10.153.34.113,255.255.255.0,0002.c18c.3148,,,
IPX,10.153.34.115,255.255.255.0,0002.c18c.30e8,,,
```

---

Use the module [*community.general.read_csv*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/read_csv_module.html#community-general-read-csv-module-read-a-csv-file) and read the file

```yaml
    - community.general.read_csv:
        path: /tmp/test.csv
        fieldnames: layer,ip,mask,mac,x1,x2,x3
      register: test
```

gives

```yaml
  test.list:
  - ip: 10.153.34.97
    layer: IPX
    mac: 0002.c18b.f128
    mask: 255.255.255.0
    x1: ''
    x2: ''
    x3: ''
  - ip: 10.153.34.101
    layer: IPX
    mac: 0002.c18b.ed10
    mask: 255.255.255.0
    x1: ''
    x2: ''
    x3: ''
  - ip: 10.153.34.104
    layer: IPX
    mac: 0002.c18c.1a43
    mask: 255.255.255.0
    x1: ''
    x2: ''
    x3: ''
  - ip: 10.153.34.111
    layer: IPX
    mac: 0002.c18b.f93e
    mask: 255.255.255.0
    x1: ''
    x2: ''
    x3: ''
  - ip: 10.153.34.113
    layer: IPX
    mac: 0002.c18c.3148
    mask: 255.255.255.0
    x1: ''
    x2: ''
    x3: ''
  - ip: 10.153.34.115
    layer: IPX
    mac: 0002.c18c.30e8
    mask: 255.255.255.0
    x1: ''
    x2: ''
    x3: ''
```

Update *mac*. Declare the variable *mac_update*

```yaml
  mac_update: "{{ test.list|
                  map(attribute='mac')|
                  map('split', '.')|
                  map('join')|
                  map('community.general.dict_kv', 'mac')|
                  list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  mac_update:
  - mac: 0002c18bf128
  - mac: 0002c18bed10
  - mac: 0002c18c1a43
  - mac: 0002c18bf93e
  - mac: 0002c18c3148
  - mac: 0002c18c30e8
```

*zip* the lists and *combine* the items. Declare the variable

```yaml
  test_update: "{{ test.list|zip(mac_update)|map('combine')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  test_update:
  - ip: 10.153.34.97
    layer: IPX
    mac: 0002c18bf128
    mask: 255.255.255.0
    x1: ''
    x2: ''
    x3: ''
  - ip: 10.153.34.101
    layer: IPX
    mac: 0002c18bed10
    mask: 255.255.255.0
    x1: ''
    x2: ''
    x3: ''
  - ip: 10.153.34.104
    layer: IPX
    mac: 0002c18c1a43
    mask: 255.255.255.0
    x1: ''
    x2: ''
    x3: ''
  - ip: 10.153.34.111
    layer: IPX
    mac: 0002c18bf93e
    mask: 255.255.255.0
    x1: ''
    x2: ''
    x3: ''
  - ip: 10.153.34.113
    layer: IPX
    mac: 0002c18c3148
    mask: 255.255.255.0
    x1: ''
    x2: ''
    x3: ''
  - ip: 10.153.34.115
    layer: IPX
    mac: 0002c18c30e8
    mask: 255.255.255.0
    x1: ''
    x2: ''
    x3: ''
```

Update the file

```yaml
    - ansible.builtin.copy:
        dest: /tmp/test.csv
        content: |
          {% for i in test_update %}
          {{ i.layer }},{{ i.ip }},{{ i.mask }},{{ i.mac }},,,
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```
shell> cat /tmp/test.csv
IPX,10.153.34.97,255.255.255.0,0002c18bf128,,,
IPX,10.153.34.101,255.255.255.0,0002c18bed10,,,
IPX,10.153.34.104,255.255.255.0,0002c18c1a43,,,
IPX,10.153.34.111,255.255.255.0,0002c18bf93e,,,
IPX,10.153.34.113,255.255.255.0,0002c18c3148,,,
IPX,10.153.34.115,255.255.255.0,0002c18c30e8,,,
```

---

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    mac_update: "{{ test.list|
                    map(attribute='mac')|
                    map('split', '.')|
                    map('join')|
                    map('community.general.dict_kv', 'mac')|
                    list }}"
    test_update: "{{ test.list|zip(mac_update)|map('combine')|list }}"

  tasks:

    - community.general.read_csv:
        path: /tmp/test.csv
        fieldnames: layer,ip,mask,mac,x1,x2,x3
      register: test

    - debug:
        var: test.list
    - debug:
        var: mac_update
    - debug:
        var: test_update

    - ansible.builtin.copy:
        dest: /tmp/test.csv
        content: |
          {% for i in test_update %}
          {{ i.layer }},{{ i.ip }},{{ i.mask }},{{ i.mac }},,,
          {% endfor %}
```

- Example of a simplified playbook that gives the same result

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - community.general.read_csv:
        path: /tmp/test.csv
        fieldnames: layer,ip,mask,mac,x1,x2,x3
      register: test

    - ansible.builtin.copy:
        dest: /tmp/test.csv
        content: |
          {% for i in test.list %}
          {{ i.layer }},{{ i.ip }},{{ i.mask }},{{ i.mac|replace('.', '') }},,,
          {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Vladimir! That worked very well! Thank you for your quick response. I tested your code and understand how to use it. I would not have guessed that method. I very much appreciate the help!

Comment: Andrew! I added simplified code too. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Vladimir, I saw your update. Thank you. I implemented the simplified code as well and appreciate it very much. All works well!